# How do I solve a rake routes error when I run the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie in Rails and I get routing errors like this:

No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/home"

I know it's because I am missing some codes in routes.rb, how do I get these routes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mori's answer is spot on.  But as a beginner, you will find the following command to be your friend:

```
rake routes
```

Good luck